# MediaWiki like directory system

Tags: php, url, subdirectory

So if you look at a mediawiki url:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

You see that the page is a subdirectory of index.php in /wiki. How can I make my script work like

http://mysite.com/users/Walter

when all I have in the users directory is index.php (and other resources to make index.php work?)

Comment: mod_rewrite is helpful: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some URL rewrite on your web server, for examples on nginx:

```
 server {
   listen 80;
   server_name wiki.example.com;

   root /var/www/mediawiki;

   location / {
     index index.php5;
     error_page 404 = @mediawiki;
   }

   location @mediawiki {
     rewrite ^/wiki([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php5?title=$1&$2 last;
   }

   location ~ \.php5?$ {
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8888;
     fastcgi_index index.php5;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
 }
```

There's a very good guide over here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added some more info. Thanks